# Deleting images from Resources/Drawable does not delete references in Android.csproj

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After I manually deleted images from Resources/Drawable folder in Android project I started receiving a build error: **Source file 'Resources\drawable\imagename.png' could not be found**. I found out that Android.csproj file was no updated, meaning the references to the images were not deleted. So the question is should I delete unnecessary images manually like this or there is some another way I have to follow, and how to fix the current problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deleting something from outside of VS, the project file won't know it was deleted which will cause errors like these if you don't wanna use something first exclude it from the project and then delete it or use VS to delete it

The best way to handle it as of now would be to go to the specific folder you will see an Exclamation mark something like below:

[image]

To handle this just delete them(from vs menu) and you should be good

Comment: I totally forgot about it. I had to see visually the images to decide whether I need them or not, that's why I used the containing folder and missed the part you've mentioned... Thanks!!

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help, Also In most VS versions hovering over the images would show you a preview hope that helps!